# Magento: Get all products from a product collection ignoring the set limits?

Tags: magento, collections

I want to iterate over all products in the product collection given in the block Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar, ignoring the limits that were set before by "setPageSize()" and "setCurPage()". My approach looks like the following:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar $this */
//...
$collection = $this->getCollection();
// Remove the LIMIT and OFFSET parts from the generated SQL query:
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
// Reload the collection using the new SQL query:
$collection->load();
foreach($collection as $product)
{
    // ...
}
// ...
```

The problem is, that the collection seems not to be reloaded, so the limits that were set before are still there. What am I missing here? Is the collection locked or something so that I can't change it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The collection you use in the product list toolbar block, usually is already loaded before and set to the toolbar instance by `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_beforeHtml()`.

Just resetting count and offset for the statement is not enough.

You additionally need to reset the properties

```
Varien_Data_Collection::_isCollectionLoaded
Varien_Data_Collection::_pageSize
```

This can be done by

```
$collection->clear();
$collection->setPageSize(false);
```

Insert these instructions between your `reset`'s and the `load` and you should be fine.

Comment: That did the trick, so collections are indeed locked after they have been loaded.

Comment: Just the clear & setPageSize followed by a load work for me. Thanks